# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' when I add Google Cloud Module

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

Clone the project https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm  and everything works perfectly.

When I try to add the module "**App Engine Backend with Google Cloud Messaging**" with the wizard I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Now I try to add this in my build.gradle defaultConfig

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

and clean the project and recompile. But I always get the same error. Finally I try to delete the form from the project (thinking to resume normal functioning) but I get the following error:

```
    Installing gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DUPLICATE_PERMISSION perm=com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE pkg=it.elipse.tnttrackingapp]


DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm uninstall gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Could someone help me? to you taking the same steps you find yourself in my situation? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Hi guys i've found by myself the answer. I hope that it can be helpfull for someone with the same problem. 
When Android Studio generates the backend module, adds this line at the end of dependencies of your build.gradle(Module:app)

```
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
```

And you have something like this :

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')

}
```

The workaround is to move the auto-generated line on the top of dependecies declaration, like this:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'  
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'  
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'

}
```

**UPDATE**

If you do not solve try:

```
Build->Make Project
Build->Make Module 'app'
Build->Clean Project
Build->Rebuild Project
```

Comment: Hey man i got same problem as urs but ur solution didn't work for me i didn't added aby library i just modified some classes do u have any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Which classes have you edit? Try to post your gradle file for try to solve it together

Comment: Thanks @Federico for ur response i have posted a question here kindly check it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068676/transformexception-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithd

Comment: Tried both but no luck.... =( it worked earlier this year but now it's a problem.

Comment: MicroR have you seen my update? Try to post your code