# TransformException : Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm getting this error after i converted list view to recycler view in my layout and i changed the adapter from base adapter to recycler view adapter

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

thats the what i m getting in log

```
    14:38:32.582 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'
14:38:32.582 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
14:38:32.584 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 41.484 secs.
14:38:32.584 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 2 mins 9.57 secs, idle: 0.244 secs
14:38:32.598 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:38:32.599 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
14:38:32.600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:38:32.600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
14:38:32.600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
14:38:32.600 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_71.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
14:38:32.601 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
14:38:32.601 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
14:38:32.603 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
14:38:32.604 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
14:38:32.604 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
14:38:32.605 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
14:38:32.605 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
14:38:32.605 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
14:38:32.605 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
14:38:32.605 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
14:38:32.605 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
14:38:32.606 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
14:38:32.606 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
14:38:32.606 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
14:38:32.606 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:62)
14:38:32.607 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
14:38:32.607 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
14:38:32.607 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
14:38:32.607 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
14:38:32.608 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
14:38:32.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
14:38:32.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
14:38:32.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
14:38:32.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
14:38:32.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
14:38:32.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
14:38:32.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
14:38:32.613 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
```

i tried to clean my project and i have added mutlidex support for my project 
any help ?

Comment: This may looks a little bit stupid, but if cleaning/rebuild and adding multiDex doesn't work, just simply try reboot your PC. It works for me.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: @Tony Few questions: Have you already upgraded to Android Studio 2.0? If true, do you have Instant Run enabled?

Comment: yes i have upgraded and instance run is enabled

Comment: Try to disable Instant Run feature (in Preferences), and then rebuild. Let me know if it works, and I'll add an answer.

Comment: same result i tried to clean and rebuild with instant run disabled

Comment: i don't know why i'm getting error in auto generated files if i clean my project

Comment: OK, need more info to understand what's failing. Try to run `./gradlew clean assembleDebug -d --full-stacktrace`. It will produce tons of logs - search for transformClassesWithDexForDebug and add everything (from this point till the end) to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97067/discussion-between-tony-and-alex-lipov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying every things available on this issue with no luck
i have fixed my problem rollback my adapter classes to their original state and create new classes, i know that's not a solution but i couldn't fix this in another way

Comment: I'm having the same damn problem right now. Never had it before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34515980/adding-google-app-engine-module-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransform?noredirect=1#comment56774171_34515980

Answer (score 4):

Have you try:

```
Build->Make Project
Build->Make Module 'app'
Build->Clean Project
Build->Rebuild Project
```

Please post your gradle file

Comment: I do not know the actual reason, but Clean and Rebuild did help.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this could help you.
I had the same problem and changing all the tags:

```
annotationProcessor
```

(grade app file)
for:

```
kapt
```

It worked for me

Comment: That's true. I think this error occurs because I still use  "annotationProcessor" when I used "kotlin-kapt" which uses "kapt" instead of. Read more in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52223088/9322624

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I got rid of this error by putting this line to the `gradle.properties` file.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

It was already in this file. I just had to remove the comment symbol in front of it.