# Android app build failing when adding GCM backend

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, dex

I want to add a Google Cloud Messaging backend to my android application (just one of the available samples). To do this, I am following the official [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints). I am deploying on my phone (a Samsung A5 with Android 5.0.2)

Before I add the backend, the application can be deployed normally.

After I add the backend, the backend can be deployed normally on the Google AppEngine dev server, and I can see it in my browser.

However, when I try to deploy the application on my device, I am getting the error in the end.

Does it have to do with my Java version (1.8)?

I noticed that dex is mentioned in the stacktrace, so perhaps it has to do with the [method number limit](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)? I wouldn't expect that, since it's a very small sample application, I don't think I may have exceeded the 64K methods.

Finally, I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34068676/transformexception-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithd), but it did not help.

---

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:backend:appengineDownloadSdk
:backend:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:backend:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:backend:classes UP-TO-DATE
:backend:appengineEndpointsGetClientLibs UP-TO-DATE
:backend:appengineEndpointsExpandClientLibs UP-TO-DATE
:backend:compileEndpointsSrcJava UP-TO-DATE
:backend:processEndpointsSrcResources UP-TO-DATE
:backend:endpointsSrcClasses UP-TO-DATE
:backend:_appengineEndpointsAndroidArtifact UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable830Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2 mins 44.821 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: [Please check this link may helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception) defaultConfig { multiDexEnabled true }

Answer (score 1):

I followed [wadali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587027/wadali)'s suggestion to check the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception/33690032#33690032). An answer by [A.Grandt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049722/a-grandt), which worked for me says:

> Another thing to watch for, is that you don't use
>
> ```
> compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
> ```
>
> That will import ALL the play services, and it'll only take little more than a hello world to exceed the 65535 method limit of a single dex APK.
>
> Always specify only the services you need

So I only kept this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
```