# What are the necessary gradle dependencies for an App Engine Backend with Google Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play-services

What are the necessary gradle dependencies for an App Engine Backend with Google Cloud Messaging?

Currently, when you add a module like that to your Android Studio project it adds this dependency:

'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'

However, when you run the project you get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java''
> >     finished with non-zero exit value 2

Someone suggested using this:

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
}
```

But that actually didn't work for me.

So it appears that I have to specify only the required libraries for GAE + GCM. So far I have:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
```

[full list here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup). But that didn't work. I got this error:

> E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an
>   expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google
>   services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or
>   com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.

So I am at a loss.

Is there some other way around this issue? What is weird is my old GAE + GCM projects work fine importing the whole google play services. Importing those older versions of google play services in my new project does not work however. So I am not sure what is going on.

**EDIT: Some more information:**

I did some tests.

1) Started new Android Studio project, added new google cloud module 'App Engine Java Endpoints Module'. The auto-generated build.grade (Module: app) looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

Result? Compiles and runs perfectly - no problems!

2) Started new Android Studio project, added new google cloud module 'App Engine Backend with Google Cloud Messaging'. the auto-generated build.grade (Module: app) looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

Result? Same crappy error I have been getting!

So it looks like the line 'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'' is the problem. I replaced it with

'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0''

since in theory that is all I need for google cloud messaging. When I run it I get this:

> 12-30 14:14:16.482 10573-10573/com.myapp.myapp
>   E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an
>   expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google
>   services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or
>   com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin. 12-30 14:14:16.482
>   10573-10573/com.myapp.myapp E/GMPM: Scheduler not
>   set. Not logging error/warn. 12-30 14:14:16.502
>   10573-10623/com.myapp.myapp E/GMPM: Uploading is
>   not possible. App measurement disabled

So it looks like I am missing this google-services.json file or something. I don't get what happened with Android Studio because several months ago I made a GCM enabled app the same way and that one compiles no problem. The gradle.build file of that app looks like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(path: ':gcm-backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

So it looks like Android Studio stopped adding the 'compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'' dependency.

So I ran a project with

```
'compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

Result? Same Execution failed error.

Ok so let's try the old play-services library in my new project:

```
'compile 'com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2'
'compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

Result? Same Execution failed error.

I just don't get why this isn't working out of the box like it used to...

Comment: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0' try this

Comment: So for `Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services` shows that you need a configure file called `google-services.json` for using play-services. For more details, please refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33083898/4186942)

Comment: @bjiang hmm I investigated but at the end of the day I think this is another problem with my mac + android studio (been using PC + android studio up to this point). I am finding my old Cloud Endpoints Android Studio projects are not working on my new mac =(

Comment: maybe you need to change your SHA1 cuz you change the computer.

Comment: @bijian See my edits - I believe it is a problem with the process of adding a new GCM module but I am at a loss as to why this doesn't work out of the box anymore.Thanks for your on going help by the way bjiang!

Comment: So the play services dependency added by the cloud tooling was updated but isn't in 1.5 (or earlier version), if you access one of the android-studio-2.0 previews, I believe it should add the correct dependency (play-services-gcm vs play-services).

Answer (score 3):

So, this should be considered an issue with Android Studio since simply adding a module 'App Engine Backend with Google Cloud Messaging' will break the build every time on even the simplest of apps, due to the full Google Play Services dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' being large enough to exceed the 65K DEX method limit on its own. This problem is actually documented in '[Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)'.

The solution is, as you had discovered, to manually edit your build.gradle and add only the import for GCM 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'. The requirement for 'google-services.json' to be added manually is normal though, since you need to generate it for your project on developers.google.com. Adding 'multiDexEnabled true' isn't a good solution, as it increases your APK size needlessly, and you still end up with duplicate dependencies.

I've created an [entry on the Android issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205192&thanks=205192&ts=1459109752) to fix the dependencies for the App Engine GCM backend module in Android Studio. Feel free to star this issue for visibility and updates.

Comment: Yes I wish Android Studio explained you need to manually add the 'google-services.json' file too (maybe navigating you to a link?) but it does not. Thank for adding.

Comment: I wish it will be explained in future, maybe in the Google documentation or in Android Studio error message, spent a lot of time on this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary tests show that this works so far.

I took at a look at the google GCM sample project here: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

And edited my gradle files. Here is what they look like now:

APP:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.me.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

PROJECT:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And also I followed [this](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) guide (see step 2) to generate a google-services.json file which I dropped into the app/ directory.

Now the app compiles and works (so far at least).

I'm really angry this doesn't work out of the box with the auto generated gradle files and that I have to hunt them down in some sample app. It didn't used to be this way just a few months ago. It worked as soon as you added the GCM module.

If anyone else has any tips/suggestions for future projects please let me know. =D

Comment: Build -> Clean Project & Rebuild Project also helps!

Comment: The sample app uses the newer mechanics for GCM compared to the instructions on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints. I'll file a bug to update the docs on github.

Answer (score 0):

If you do get to the stage where you need to run with MultiDex enabled, there are three steps you need to do:

1. Enable it in your defaultConfig in Gradle as you already tried:

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       minSdkVersion 14
       targetSdkVersion 21
       ...

       // Enabling multidex support.
       multiDexEnabled true
   }
   ```
2. Include it in your dependencies:

   ```
   dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
   }
   ```
3. Add it to your manifest:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
       <application
           ...
           android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
           ...
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```

https://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/building/multidex.html#about

But always have a good look at the dependencies you already have as it's usually not needed.