# Android project with Java and Kotlin files, kapt or annotationProcessor?

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, apt, kapt

I would like to know if in an **Android** project mixing **Java** and **Kotlin** files we must use annotationProcessor or kapt, or both ?

In my understanding **annotationProcessor** must be used for **Java** files using annotations for code generation, and **kapt** must be used for **Kotlin** files using annotations for code generation.

I have a project mixing both languages, and I just have replaced all the annotationProcessor dependencies in the build.gradle by kapt.
Surprisingly it builds and seems to run correctly but I do not understand why kapt works well even with Java files...

Can someone explain to me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First of all, the Kotlin Annotation processing tool (kapt) uses the Java compiler to run annotation processors. If your project contains any Java classes, kapt takes care of them by design. [Kotlinlang](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html#using-in-gradle) recommends using `kapt` incase you used `annotationProcessor` from the Android Support before.

JetBrains has a nice [article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/better-annotation-processing-supporting-stubs-in-kapt/) about how kapt works in more detail, its from 2015 but UP-TO-DATE.

Answer (score 34):

In Java you can specify annotationProcessor (or apt) dependency like below:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger-version"
}
```

In Kotlin you have to add the `kotlin-kapt` plugin to enable kapt, and then replace `annotationProcessor` with `kapt`:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt' //Must include
dependencies {
    ...
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger-version"
}
```

That's all! Note that kapt takes care of your Java files as well as kotlin file, so you don't need to keep the annotationProcessor dependency.

For more details: [link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-frameworks.html)

Comment: I tried adding 
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt',
the application could not build, and now I can't use anything that needs kapt, any idea how to solve this @Oxalihan

Comment: Is there anyway `annotationProcessor` configuration would also pick up `kotlin` files?