# Dagger 2 class component not generated

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dagger-2

i am facing issue from last 2 days. Currently , i am using Android studio Giraffe version. i am unable to get daggerComponent class. here is my code .

---

this is my app level gradle file

```
`      plugins {   
        id("com.android.application")    
            id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")    
          id("kotlin-android")        
        id("kotlin-kapt")        
           }


   android {    
       namespace = "com.example.myapplication"    
      compileSdk = 34

 defaultConfig {

  applicationId = "com.example.myapplication"
  minSdk = 24
  targetSdk = 34
  versionCode = 1
  versionName = "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

kapt{
    generateStubs=true
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        isMinifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro"
        )
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
  }

}

dependencies {

implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")

kapt ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.7.0")


implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger:2.48")
implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.48")
implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.48")

annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.48")

 //    kapt ("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.48")

annotationProcessor("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.48")
kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.48")

compileOnly("org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28")

 //    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:1.9.0")

compileOnly("javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0")
implementation("javax.inject:javax.inject:1")

}`
```

NOTE:- those dependencies which i did comment is actually showing me error while rebuild.

Here is my Project level gradle file

```
`// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules. plugins {   
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false 
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false 
   }`
```

and Here is my component interface

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = \[NetworkModule::class\])
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)

}
```

and this is the class where i want to call DaggerComponent class

```
class FakerApplication : Application() {

    lateinit var applicationComponent: ApplicationComponent
    
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    
    
    }

}
```

I have tried all stackoverflow's answer but not getting any benefit. whenever i am trying to implement kapt dependency it is showing me error. help me to resolve this issue. Thankyou

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does your failed compilation have an error message? It would be helpful for you to edit your question with your [compiler and Gradle errors from Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16633956/1426891).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the README.md printed on https://github.com/google/dagger, in the Gradle section's Notes:

> For Kotlin projects, use `kapt` in place of `annotationProcessor`.

The Gradle file in your question contains both `annotationProcessor` and `kapt` lines for both `com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.48` and `com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.48`. As in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50027741/1426891), your build will work fine for both Java and Kotlin if you use just the `kapt` lines instead of `annotationProcessor` lines for both `dagger-compiler` and `dagger-android-processor`.

There might be other reasons that your build is failing, and pasting your error message into your question may help with further diagnosis. However, in any case, you are not intended to include both the `annotationProcessor` and `kapt` lines for the same processor.

---

*Note for future readers:* As of September 2023, [kapt is in maintenance mode](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kapt.html), to be replaced by Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP). Dagger 2.48 is the first release to contain [an alpha release of Dagger's KSP processor](https://github.com/google/dagger/releases/tag/dagger-2.48) and [corresponding KSP documentation](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/ksp).