# Google Cloud Endpoints + Googles Maps API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints

I am developing an Android application that leverages Google Cloud Endpoints and Google Maps API. I am running into this issue when I am running the app.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_73.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

I have done some research and found some methods involving clearing some of the dependencies in the gradles, and editing the default config to use multiDexEnabled. However, I am still running into the issue.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.project"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of factors that might be causing this issue. Have you tried anything else besides adding the `multiDexEnabled true` in your gradle file? I have found the answers to these similar posts: [TransformException](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32807587/6124253), [ProcessException](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28917696/6124253), [ExecException](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30001051/6124253) that might be helpful for you. Most of them refer to the jars as the cause of the error. Try out their suggestions, maybe one of them might work for you, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Also found this similar post where he uses the [Google Cloud Module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288089/execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-when-i-add-google-cloud-module)